# In Vue.js Web page does not update when state changes via update in nested objects?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

In Vue.js, there are methods; Vue.set for adding and Vue.delete for deleting but for 'update' there are no Vue methods, instead you use Object.assign. Actually this is working fine if there are no changes in nested Objects. Is there a function in Vue like update or refresh, because I see state changed in Chrome Vue Extension tab but do not see the change in web page.

Vue view doesn't triggered for updates.

Example: When I added an item to "houses", I can't see the new house on the page, even I can see new item over inspect Vue, state. I can see the new item when I reload the page.

```
    "clients": {
    "oES4H0IMsYaCvGkSDKLmXkOkgXR2": {
        "CL_937fef22-cee7-4b14-9e4d-4e6751c82dab": {
            "name": "Adina Dowless",
            "email": "adinadowless@test.com",
            "phone": "(547) 515 53 91",
            "houses": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "sugarless",
                    "uavt": "832677187473",
                    "housePolicyId": "PO_7f12d27f-245b-41a6-92b4-dacb0256ccac",
                    "daskPolicyId": "PO_f5fba094-7272-41f8-a406-f9251df5a37f"
                },
                "1": {
                    "name": "intersexualism",
                    "uavt": "931095588844",
                    "housePolicyId": "PO_2d6b79d2-53a0-42f9-8445-df06c3b3bc5a",
                    "daskPolicyId": "PO_79f37178-0714-4c19-aa24-204ea3cf30e7"
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

Edit: I am using Quasar Framework, Vuex Library & Firabase Realtime Database.

So This clients object in a vuex store and initial data is coming from Firebase Database.

When adding client : `Vue.set(state.clients, payload.id, payload.client)`
When deleting client : `Vue.delete(state.clients, id)`
When updating  client : `Object.assign(state.clients[payload.id], payload.updates)`

These functions are working properly when adding, deleting or updating clients first level properties like name or email,

When adding a new house into houses, firebase databse child_changed callback for clients is triggered, with all the updated data, but component in web page does not update.

Comment: `instead you use Object.assign`, no you don't. You just directly assign with an `=` sign.

Comment: How are you adding the item to `houses`? If it's a new property then you'd just use `set`.

Comment: I use firebase database, so I add item to 'houses' over, firebase database api, on 'child_changed' callback for 'clients'. So even I add an object, I am trying to handle this in the update mutation

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a special method for doing updates. That's what `Vue` does on its own. But `Vue` **only tracks keys** that are present at the creation of a component.

Adding a new property to an existing object is not tracked by Vue.

You need to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) when adding new properties on an object so `Vue` knows to track the new properties as well.

So I think you should use `Vue.set` on the `house` object, or use `Object.assign` to create a new object.

Side note: it seems like you're using `houses` as an object when it's probably better off as an array. If you change it to array and use `Array.push` then `Vue` will track the changes. If you want to assign new items to the array at a specific index you should use [Vue.set for arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very enlightening, by the way I think I skipped some information about the problem, like I am using quasar framework and vuex library I will update my question.